# How to copy functionality of RewriteRule & RewriteBase

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following at the document root of my server i.e. www.doodle.com/.htaccess

```
Options +MultiViews
ErrorDocument 404 /x/404.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^view/([a-f0-9]{40})/$ ./view/index.php?profile_id=$1
</IfModule>
```

This produces the following:

> www.doodle.com/view/32e3234eafsd/

Say I wanted to **copy** the exact functionality within a sub directroy i.e. www.doodle.com/x/

and produce the following:

> www.doodle.com/x/view/3223433242/

Notice the /x/ subdirectory, Am I missing a simple trick here?

Can you help with a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Notice that the ids should be 40 characters long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `/x/` subdirectory:

```
RewriteRule ^x/view/([a-f0-9]{40})/$ /x/view/index.php?profile_id=$1 [L]
```

If you wanted to **copy** the htaccess file into a directory named "x", then you need to modify your rewrite base:

```
Options +MultiViews
ErrorDocument 404 /x/404.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /x/
    RewriteRule ^view/([a-f0-9]{40})/$ view/index.php?profile_id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and get rid of the `./` in front of the rule's target.

Comment: to which, the document root .htaccess?

Comment: @Chris yes, or if you are copying the htaccess file to the `/x/` folder, see the second part of answer

Comment: Thanks Jon, much appreciated! reputation++ :)